# Calcular el porcentaje y cambie automáticamente el resto según su precio

Tags: javascript

tengo una tabla donde ingreso unos productos con `<select>` los cuales tienen un valor que estoy mostrando con **fetch**, lo que necesito es que segun su valor de costo final determine un porcentaje,

muestro la tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien en la tabla tengo cantidad, precio unitario, valor de adquisición (cant * pre) y el porcentaje.

Ahora el porcentaje si lo esta calculando pero no de la forma correcta, debería ser así:

porcentaje = ((valor_adquisición / suma_total)*100)

porcentaje = ((448/ 1344)*100) = 33.33%

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito ayuda, con el calculo del porcentaje, el código javascript:

```
function Total_activos() {
const rows = document.getElementsByClassName("t_calculo_activo");
let total = 0;
let porcent = 0

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    const cantidad = rows[i].getElementsByClassName('valor_cant')[0].value;
    const precio = rows[i].getElementsByClassName('valor_prec')[0].value;
    const valor_Adqui = (cantidad * precio);

    rows[i].getElementsByClassName('valor_adqui')[0].value = valor_Adqui.toFixed(2);
    total += valor_Adqui; 
    porcent = total

    const valor_porcen = ((valor_Adqui / porcent)*100);

    rows[i].getElementsByClassName('valor_porcentaje')[0].value = valor_porcen.toFixed(2);
  }

   var activo_suma = total;
   document.getElementById('total_adqui').innerHTML = activo_suma.toFixed(2);
}
```

HTML

```
<tbody id="t_addfilas_acti" class="t-inversiones-body">
                            @php ($cant_tivo = 1)
                            @foreach ($inversiones_activos as $item)
                            <tr class="t_fila_inv_a t_calculo_activo" id="tr_iver_act_{{$cant_tivo}}">
                                <td>
                                    <select name="tipo_activo[]" id="select_opcion_ac_{{$cant_tivo}}" onkeyup="Total_activos(this);" onchange="OpcionChange_ac('select_opcion_ac_{{$cant_tivo}}', 'select_escoger_ac_{{$cant_tivo}}')" class=" form-control form-control-sm-custom">      
                                        @if ( $item->tipo_activo == null )                                                   
                                        <option value="0">Seleccionar...</option>
                                            @else
                                            <option value="{{$item->tipo_activo}}">{{$item->tipo_activo}}</option>
                                        @endif
                                            @foreach ($proformas as $item2)
                                                <option value="{{$item2->descripcion}}" >{{$item2->descripcion}}</option>
                                            @endforeach                                     
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="activos_fijos[]" readonly value="{{$item->activos_fijos}}"></td>
                                {{-- cantidad --}}
                                <td class="pre-c"><input type="number" step="0.01" name="cantidad_fijos[]" class="valor_cant" onkeyup="Total_activos();" value="{{$item->cantidad_fijos}}"></td>
                                {{-- precio unidad --}}
                                <td class="pre-d" id="select_escoger_ac_{{$cant_tivo}}">
                                    <input type="text" step="0.01" name="precio_fijos[]" class="valor_prec" onkeyup="Total_activos();" readonly value="{{$item->precio_fijos}}">
                                </td>
                                {{-- valor Adquisición --}}
                                <td class="pre-d"><input type="number" step="0.01" name="valor_fijos[]" class="valor_adqui" onkeyup="Total_activos();" readonly value="{{$item->valor_fijos}}"></td>
                                {{-- porcentaje --}}
                                <td class="pre-d"><input type="number" step="0.01" name="porcentaje_fijos[]" class="valor_porcentaje" onkeyup="Total_activos();" readonly value="{{$item->porcentaje_fijos}}"></td>    
                                <td><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></td>                           
                            </tr> 
                            @php ($cant_tivo++)
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
```

Como se ve en la imagen si hace de forma correcta pero no modifica los anteriores y eso es lo que necesito, que calcule el porcentaje y cambie automáticamente el resto.

Comment: olvide comentar que las tablas son dinámicas entonces la cantidad de filas son desconocidas, para este ejemplo utilice solo 3 pero pueden ser "n" filas.

Comment: Si las filas bienen de una base de datos, podrias calcular el total y usarlo para calcular el porcentaje, de lo contrario podrias darle una clase a la columna y asignar el porcentaje despues de calcular el total.

Comment: @alanfcm no, las filas las agregaría el usuario, con un botón en forma de "+"

Comment: Entonces puedes agregar la clase, si incluyes tu HTML seria mas facil de responder.

Comment: @alanfcm, listo agregue el html de tbody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso necesitas dos bucles, uno para calcular el total y el otro para asignar porcentajes.  Puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
function Total_activos() {
const rows = document.getElementsByClassName("t_calculo_activo");
let total = 0;
let porcent = 0

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    const cantidad = rows[i].getElementsByClassName('valor_cant')[0].value;
    const precio = rows[i].getElementsByClassName('valor_prec')[0].value;
    const valor_Adqui = (cantidad * precio);

    rows[i].getElementsByClassName('valor_adqui')[0].value = valor_Adqui.toFixed(2);
    total += valor_Adqui; 
    porcent = total
    
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    const cantidad = rows[i].getElementsByClassName('valor_cant')[0].value;
    const precio = rows[i].getElementsByClassName('valor_prec')[0].value;
    const valor_Adqui = (cantidad * precio);
    
    const valor_porcen = ((valor_Adqui / total)*100);

    rows[i].getElementsByClassName('valor_porcentaje')[0].value = valor_porcen.toFixed(2);
  }

   var activo_suma = total;
   document.getElementById('total_adqui').innerHTML = activo_suma.toFixed(2);
}
Total_activos();
```

```html
<table>
<tbody id="t_addfilas_acti" class="t-inversiones-body">
                            <tr class="t_fila_inv_a t_calculo_activo" id="tr_iver_act_{{$cant_tivo}}">
                                <td>
                                    <select name="tipo_activo[]" id="select_opcion_ac_{{$cant_tivo}}" onkeyup="Total_activos(this);" onchange="OpcionChange_ac('select_opcion_ac_{{$cant_tivo}}', 'select_escoger_ac_{{$cant_tivo}}')" class=" form-control form-control-sm-custom">      
                                        <option value="0">Seleccionar...</option>
                                            <option value="{{$item->tipo_activo}}">{{$item->tipo_activo}}</option>             
                                                <option value="{{$item2->descripcion}}" >{{$item2->descripcion}}</option>                                         
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="activos_fijos[]" readonly value="{{$item->activos_fijos}}"></td>                                
                                <td class="pre-c"><input type="number" step="0.01" name="cantidad_fijos[]" class="valor_cant" onkeyup="Total_activos();" value="1"></td> 
                                <td class="pre-d" id="select_escoger_ac_{{$cant_tivo}}">
                                    <input type="text" step="0.01" name="precio_fijos[]" class="valor_prec" onkeyup="Total_activos();" readonly value="448">
                                </td>                                
                                <td class="pre-d"><input type="number" step="0.01" name="valor_fijos[]" class="valor_adqui" onkeyup="Total_activos();" readonly value="{{$item->valor_fijos}}"></td>                                
                                <td class="pre-d porcentaje"><input type="number" step="0.01" name="porcentaje_fijos[]" class="valor_porcentaje" onkeyup="Total_activos();" readonly value="{{$item->porcentaje_fijos}}"></td>    
                                <td><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></td>   
                            </tr> 
                            <tr class="t_fila_inv_a t_calculo_activo" id="tr_iver_act_{{$cant_tivo}}">
                                <td>
                                    <select name="tipo_activo[]" id="select_opcion_ac_{{$cant_tivo}}" onkeyup="Total_activos(this);" onchange="OpcionChange_ac('select_opcion_ac_{{$cant_tivo}}', 'select_escoger_ac_{{$cant_tivo}}')" class=" form-control form-control-sm-custom">      
                                        <option value="0">Seleccionar...</option>
                                            <option value="{{$item->tipo_activo}}">{{$item->tipo_activo}}</option>             
                                                <option value="{{$item2->descripcion}}" >{{$item2->descripcion}}</option>                                         
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="activos_fijos[]" readonly value="{{$item->activos_fijos}}"></td>                                
                                <td class="pre-c"><input type="number" step="0.01" name="cantidad_fijos[]" class="valor_cant" onkeyup="Total_activos();" value="1"></td>  
                                <td class="pre-d" id="select_escoger_ac_{{$cant_tivo}}">
                                    <input type="text" step="0.01" name="precio_fijos[]" class="valor_prec" onkeyup="Total_activos();" readonly value="448">
                                </td>                                
                                <td class="pre-d"><input type="number" step="0.01" name="valor_fijos[]" class="valor_adqui" onkeyup="Total_activos();" readonly value="{{$item->valor_fijos}}"></td>                                
                                <td class="pre-d porcentaje"><input type="number" step="0.01" name="porcentaje_fijos[]" class="valor_porcentaje" onkeyup="Total_activos();" readonly value="{{$item->porcentaje_fijos}}"></td>    
                                <td><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></td>   
                            </tr> 
                            <tr class="t_fila_inv_a t_calculo_activo" id="tr_iver_act_{{$cant_tivo}}">
                                <td>
                                    <select name="tipo_activo[]" id="select_opcion_ac_{{$cant_tivo}}" onkeyup="Total_activos(this);" onchange="OpcionChange_ac('select_opcion_ac_{{$cant_tivo}}', 'select_escoger_ac_{{$cant_tivo}}')" class=" form-control form-control-sm-custom">      
                                        <option value="0">Seleccionar...</option>
                                            <option value="{{$item->tipo_activo}}">{{$item->tipo_activo}}</option>             
                                                <option value="{{$item2->descripcion}}" >{{$item2->descripcion}}</option>                                         
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="activos_fijos[]" readonly value="{{$item->activos_fijos}}"></td>                                
                                <td class="pre-c"><input type="number" step="0.01" name="cantidad_fijos[]" class="valor_cant" onkeyup="Total_activos();" value="1"></td>  
                                <td class="pre-d" id="select_escoger_ac_{{$cant_tivo}}">
                                    <input type="text" step="0.01" name="precio_fijos[]" class="valor_prec" onkeyup="Total_activos();" readonly value="448">
                                </td>                                
                                <td class="pre-d"><input type="number" step="0.01" name="valor_fijos[]" class="valor_adqui" onkeyup="Total_activos();" readonly value="{{$item->valor_fijos}}"></td>                                
                                <td class="pre-d porcentaje"><input type="number" step="0.01" name="porcentaje_fijos[]" class="valor_porcentaje" onkeyup="Total_activos();" readonly value="{{$item->porcentaje_fijos}}"></td>    
                                <td><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></td>   
                            </tr> 
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                        <tr id="total_adqui">
                        </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                        </table>
```

Comment: funciona y cumple lo que necesito. Te agradezco un montón.